# Chromium won't start on Lubuntu 14.10

Tags: lubuntu, 14.10, chromium

Linux/Lubuntu is new to me, so I am having some trouble. I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this problem. Here is what I got as a response, when trying to run Chromium from terminal:

```
     #
# Fatal error in ../../v8/src/ia32/assembler-ia32.cc, line 55
# CHECK(cpu.has_sse2()) failed
#

==== C stack trace ===============================


     1: ??
     2: ??
     3: ??
     4: ??
     5: ??
     6: v8::V8::Initialize()
     7: gin::IsolateHolder::Initialize(gin::IsolateHolder::ScriptMode, v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator*)
     8: net::ProxyResolverV8::EnsureIsolateCreated()
     9: ??
    10: ??
    11: ??
    12: base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask(char const*, char const*, base::PendingTask const&)
    13: base::MessageLoop::RunTask(base::PendingTask const&)
    14: base::MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask(base::PendingTask const&)
    15: base::MessageLoop::DoWork()
    16: base::MessagePumpLibevent::Run(base::MessagePump::Delegate*)
    17: base::MessageLoop::RunHandler()
    18: base::RunLoop::Run()
    19: base::MessageLoop::Run()
    20: base::Thread::Run(base::MessageLoop*)
    21: content::BrowserThreadImpl::IOThreadRun(base::MessageLoop*)
    22: content::BrowserThreadImpl::Run(base::MessageLoop*)
    23: base::Thread::ThreadMain()
    24: ??
    25: ??
    26: clone
    Illegal instruction (core dumped)
    kd@kd:~$ ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
```

Answer (score 1):

Chromium dropped support for running on processors that don't have SSE2 a few versions ago. I believe this primarily impacts those who have i386 Athlon processors, as those don't have SSE2. You can check to see if you have SSE2 by running `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags`. If SSE2 is not in the output, then you don't have SSE2

If you still want to use Google Chrome or Chromium, you'll have to install an older version of Chromium.

References:

- [Bug report that required SSE2](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348761)